# Put \cite in Figure caption, but don't want to show this in TOC

Tags: citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cite in the caption of a graphic but not in \listoffigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/cite-in-the-caption-of-a-graphic-but-not-in-listoffigures)

I have a question regarding \cite and List Of Figures

For instance, I declared this

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/heike/seamless_connection}
  \caption[Seamless Connection of Network \cite{vision4g}]{Seamless Connection of Network \cite{vision4g}}
  \label{Seamless}
\end{figure}
```

However, the \cite in caption is causing the List of Figures also show this citing next to the title of Figure.

For instance in my List of Figure, I see something like

```
Seamless Connection of Network [1].....................20
```

As my documents List of Figure (LOF) is located before the table of content, they all show the reference number next to the Figure in LOF.

This caused when I tried to reference something to `"some words \cite{otherciting}"` on page 1 chapter 1, it will show as `"some words [2]"`. While actually the first thing that come is some words, so I expect it to have "some words [1].

This get worse if for instance I have 20 Figures with each reference and all are shown in List of Figures, then the "some words" will refer to [21] although this is in page 1.

I used IEEEtran for bilbiography..

I can do a work around by putting the LOF after conclussion, but I just want to know if there is a work around for this.

Thank you for any response

Comment: See also [Citations in caption as separate argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/citations-in-captions-as-separate-argument).

Comment: the basic latex document classes use the [optional] caption text in the list of figures, so you should simply not include the `\cite` in this optional text.